# Programmatically check for content type availability in subscribed sites

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, managed-metadata, content-type-hub

I have a multi-tenant SharePoint 2013 farm, which has Managed Metadata Service enabled in Multi-Tenant mode. In a Tenant, I have a Content Type Hub site where I have programmatically created Content Types. These Content Types are getting subscribed into the subscribing sites once the Content Type Subscriber job runs (I have configured this to run every minute).

In the site settings of the subscribing site, I go to the Content Type Publishing link and click on `Refresh Content Types on next update`. Once everything is successful, I see the content types listed in the same page itself.

Now, is there a way to **check programmatically**, if the content types are available in the subscribed site?